# problemas con array en apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo problemas para pasar la informacion desde spreadsheet hasta un html con apps script.

les explico;
tengo una hoja de spreadsheet que contiene 5 columnas y 5 renglones, pero son formulas, de concatenacion y otras.

desde un template html de appscript, mando llamar los datos con la siguiente instrucion;

```
var articulos = hojaEVA.getRange(1,1,5,5).getValues();
```

despues hago un `return articulos;` para enviarla a HTML, pero me marca un error diciendo que no se puede usar el return con ese tipo de datos.

pero solo me pasa cuando mi `.getRange(1,1,5,5).getValues();` tiene formulas, si son datos solos no marca error.

Comment: ya encontre mi problema, no era por las formulas, era porque una columna era de fecha, la pase a texto y funciono sin problemas

Comment: Que bueno que encontraste tu mismo la solución al problema. Para la próxima ocasión considera incluir un [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya encontre mi problema, no era por las formulas, era porque una columna era de fecha, la pase a texto y funciono sin problemas.